# How can I setup JBoss Dev Studio project imported from Red Hat BPM Suite 6.4 to build Java

Tags: java, git, maven, jboss-developer-studio, redhat-bpm

Following the instructions from the Red Hat BPM Suite Getting Started Guide and Developers Guide, I have imported a repo using Git into JBoss Developer Studio (DevStudio) as a "general project".  This lets me edit my bpmn files and push changes into BPM Suite.  However, what I need to do is add Java classes that will be used for Script and/or Service tasks.  With the project setup as a "general project" in DevStudio, it doesn't have a classpath, source folders, etc...

The pom files for projects within the repo have pom files, but there is no pom file at the top level, so DevStudio won't convert to a Maven project.

What is the recommended setup for this?  Add a top level pom to include the projects as submodules?

Here is my current project imported from BPM Suite:

```
repository1/
  project1/
    global/...
    src/
      main/
        java/
          org/...
      resources/...
    test/...
    package-name-white-list
    pom.xml
    project.imports
    project.repositories
  readme.md
```

Comment: See the guide: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_bpm_suite/6.2/html-single/development_guide/#chap-Using_JBoss_Developer_Studio_to_Create_and_Test_Processes
hope ot helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing one project folder (rather than the top-level repository folder) as a maven project instead.  Consider adding a jBPM-runtime to your project if it contains Java classes that depend on the jBPM APIs.